# Silverlight: how to display multiple properties of an object in a ListBox using DisplayMemberPath 

Tags: silverlight, listbox

I need to do this in code, **not** XAML.

Comment: One key peice of information is missing, at any one time does the list provided as an itemsource contain different types of objects.  In other words are there different lists of homogenous items that you want to display or do you have a single list of hetrogenous items.

Comment: Oh BTW, could you simplify the title.  Also collect the extra info you placed in the comments in answers so far and create a more rounded out question, in terms of quesion quality this one is quite poor at the moment.

Comment: there are different lists of homogeneous items, at runtime it will be decided which list to give as itemSource,and the properties to bind also needs to be decided at runtime...
Thanks Anothony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to programmatically create the content of a data template in the same way you might create Controls and add them to a `UserControl`.

Instead you will need to use `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` to construct the DataTemplate as XML with `DataTemplate` being the root element.  Once complete you can retrieve the XML string for the Root element and then use `XamlReader.Load` to get a constructed `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

With a ListBox, you can specify a DataItemTemplate - just put whatever controls you want in that DataItemTemplate (e.g. you might want multiple TextBlocks), and bind them to whatever properties you want on the bound object.

To load the DataItemTemplate dynamically, you can use the same technique as illustrated in [this blog post](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2010/01/dynamic-controltemplate-in-silverlight.html).

Comment: See my edit....... the blog post uses a ControlTemplate, but you can do the same with DataTemplate.

Comment: can i make the DataTemplate at runtime, because i dont know what type of objects will come into my list and what properties will they have,
i have a requirement of of dynamically selecting a object type and then select its properties to be displayed in list box